# Assigning a Pointer through a Double Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, double-pointer

```
int m = 5, n = 6;
int *p,*q,**r;
p = &n, q = &n;
r = &p;
cout<<m<<n<<*p<<*q<<**r; \\Gives output 56666
*r = &m;
cout<<m<<n<<*p<<*q<<**r;  \\Gives output 56665
```

Shouldn't the output be 56565 as when you give *r = &m, p gets the address of m and *p should print the value of m (5)?

Comment: C# and C are not the same language. Please try to only use tags relevant to your question.

Comment: Speaking of relevant tags... I think you meant to tag C++.

Comment: Yes, my bad. I meant to add C++.

Comment: Speaking of your example. Did you actually compile and run the code you posted? For one comments are made with `//`, and not `\\ `. Also, you print everything on a single line. So that would not produce two different lines. And finally, when I fixed those mistakes. I got the expected results. http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a13ef45d32b36202

Comment: I get 56565 as expected https://ideone.com/A8elMA how did you come up with 56665? What compiler/platform?

Answer (score 2):

> Shouldn't the output be 56565 as when you give *r = &m, p gets the address of m and *p should print the value of m (5)?

Yes, it should; your reasoning is spot on. Furthermore, the [output **is** 56565](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c759976e3b6f5222), as it should be.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way pointers works.

if `r=&p` and you set `*r=&m` it is exactly the same as `p=&m`.